# How do I fully characterize these subsets.

Tags: category-theory

I'm working through the following,

> Exercise 2.1.iv. A functor $F$ defines a *subfunctor* of $G$ if there is a natural transformation $\alpha: F \Rightarrow G$ whose components are monomorphisms. In the case of $G: C^{op} → \operatorname{Set}$, a subfunctor is given by a collection of subsets $Fc \subset Gc$ so that each $Gf : Gc \longrightarrow Gc'$ restricts to a function $Ff: Fc → Fc'$. Characterize those subsets that assemble into a subfunctor of the representable functor $C(−, c)$.

I am wanting to know how do I fully characterize these subsets they speak of. I saw that this was already asked but it feels incomplete.

The person says that it is a collection of morphisms with codomain $c$ that are closed under precompositions with morphisms in $\textbf{C}$. My question is how do we prove that instead of show it like they did.

Comment: I think what is wanted is just for you to find the notion of "sieve" on $c$. For that you just need to make explicit what $C(-,c)(f)$ is, for $f:d\to d'$, and then write in full words what "$Gf$ restricts to a function $Fd\to Fd'$" means in this case

Comment: It can be hard to answer to such kind of questions if you don't specify the source of said problem, because one lacks the background knowledge the exercise suppose.

Comment: You should be more explicit about what was lacking in previous answers, otherwise you're likely to get another answer that "feels incomplete".

Comment: The person says that it is a collection of morphisms with codomain $c$ that are closed under precompositions with morphisms in $\textbf{C}$. My question is how do we prove that instead of show it like they did.